# Axios/Vuex api query not working, error in params argument

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, vuex

I am using Axios and Vuex in a Vue app which queries the iTunes API, but having problem with getting the entered value from the search/text field. An error is shown for the params argument in the query string. Code is below.

Search box

```
<v-text-field 
  v-model="search" 
  autofocus 
  @keyup.enter="searchData(params)" 
  label="Enter Artists Name" 
  append-icon="search">
</v-text-field>
```

And the searchData function is

```
async searchData({ params }) {
  let config = {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
  }
  const response = await this.$http.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/search? term=${params.id}&entity=album`, config);
  //store.commit('add', response.data.results);
  console.log(response.data.results);
}
}
```

The error is

> Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

at keyup.

So trying to pass the artist name which is put in search box, but not working?

Any tips welcome, Thanks

Comment: Is `params` a computed property which uses the `search` data property _(field value)_? Is `params` an Object with a `params` property? If not, please show where `params` come from. But I find it weird that you do `async searchData({params})` instead of just `searchData(params)`

Comment: Yes its just field value, not an object, must have been asleep.!

Answer (score 2):

Try below

```
<v-text-field
      v-model="search"
      autofocus
      @keyup="searchData($event)"
      label="Enter Artists Name"
      append-icon="search"
    ></v-text-field>
```

searchData function

```
async searchData(event: any) {

    console.log("value: ", event.target.value)
    console.log("search: ", this.search)
    // let config = {
    //   headers: {
    //     'Accept': 'application/json'
    //   }
    // }
    // const response = await this.$http.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/search? 
    //   term=${params.id}&entity=album`, config);
    // //store.commit('add', response.data.results);
    // console.log(response.data.results);
    //}
  }
```

either you can use the global variable "search" or "event.target.value". this is working with TypeScript version. Should work with the JS as well.

Comment: Ah, yes of course. it is not accessing any api, just an entered field, like artist "madonna" or whatever, to put in the axios get request where this is "${params.id}" so request would look like await this.$http.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/search? 
    //   term=madonna&entity=album`, config);   so I need the  entered value, as you said. Thanks

Comment: This worked, using  in the search field  @keyup.enter="searchData($event)" and in the function let artist = $event.target.value
      const response = await this.$http.get(`https://itunes.apple.com/search?term=artist&entity=album`, config);
            //store.commit('add', response.data.results);
            //this.response = response.data
            console.log(artist)
            console.log(response)

Answer (score 1):

This method:

```
@keyup.enter="searchData(params)"
```

Is a `Vue` event and not a native event. So `params` in this case is just the value of the text field. It is not an object. You cannot destructure `params` in the func argument, and you cannot access `id` off of it, as it will not be an object.